# Voltar o focus para a janela que abriu a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

Tenho o seguinte código que abre uma janela *popup* `janela.php` onde recebo alguns dados do banco de dados:

```
<script>
$("button").click(function(){
    window.open("janela.php", "_blank", "width=400, height=500");
});
</script>
```

Na janela *popup* aberta, existe um botão onde o usuário clica para enviar dados para a janela principal (`opener`), a que abriu a *popup*:

```
<script>
$(".botao").click(function(){
    // outros códigos aqui que não vem ao caso
    $(window.opener.document).find("#status").text("Salvo!");
});
</script>
```

Tudo funciona perfeitamente.

**Dúvida:** como fazer para que, ao clicar no botão `.botao` na `popup`, o *focus* passe da *popup* para a janela principal (`opener`)? Ou seja, ao clicar no botão, a *popup* passe para segundo plano e a janela `opener` fique em primeiro plano na tela.

> Precisaria de algo *crossbrowser*, que funcione nos navegadores
>   Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, IE (pelo menos no 11) e Edge.

Comment: Você pode adicionar foco com `.focus()`, mas não é possível minimizar a janela aberta (ao menos Chrome). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Note_on_use_of_window_open

Comment: Já tentei mas não funcionou.

Comment: Creio que fazer isso com JavaScript não seja possível. Uma possível alternativa seria criar um modal personalizado na página...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei uma solução para os navegadores citados (falando de navegadores mais modernos, em abril/2018).

Antes, é necessário setar um `name` para janela principal (`opener`), qualquer `name`. Basta colocar no script da janela principal:

```
<script>
name = "principal";
</script>
```

E o código na *popup* para os navegadores:

### - IE 11, Edge, Safari:

```
window.open('', window.opener.name);
```

### - Chrome, Opera, Safari:

```
window.opener.focus();
```

### - Firefox:

Só funciona com as duas linhas ao mesmo tempo:

```
window.open('', window.opener.name);
window.opener.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Não tenho pontos suficientes para poder comentar, por isso estou respondendo aqui.

Teste o seguinte código, executando juntamente com o seu já feito

```
<script>
$(".botao").click(function(){
$(window.opener.document).find("#status").text("Salvo!");
window.opener.focus(''); // joga o foco para janela que abriu a popup  
window.blur(); // tira o foco da popup
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa seria você executar todas as ações necessárias e, em seguida, realizar um *blur*, um *focus* no campo *status* e finalmente fechar o popup.

```
$(".botao").click(function () {
    //...
    window.opener.$("#status").val("Salvo!");

    window.opener.$("#status").blur();
    window.opener.$("#status").focus();
    window.close();
});
```

Porém, nesse caso, você será forçado a fechar o popup e precisará escolher um campo da janela principal que receberá o foco.

Encontrei um [tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601790/minimize-browser-window-using-javascript) a respeito de "minimizar" ou trocar o foco entre popups e janela pai via JavaScript mas pelo visto isso não é possível.